How to obtain the *actual* URL of an image?
Consider the following html page:


function correctTitle() {
    const imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
    const titleElement = document.getElementById('image-title');
    titleElement.textContent = 'Image URL: '+imageElement.getAttribute("src");
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="image-title">Loading...</h1>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris">
        <img id="image" src="https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris" onLoad="correctTitle()")>
    </a>
</body>
</html>



This loads an image from the web and displays it, then updates its title to show its URL.
The image is referenced by its URL:
https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris
However, when opening the image directly in the browser (by clicking on it), the address bar of the browser shows its actual URL:
https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/defaultImage.small_320_240_g.jpg
How should I modify the code to display the actual URL, and not the URL used as reference?

The request to retrieve the image is being redirected to a different resource location when it's received by the server. Your client side logic will have no knowledge of that change of location, so there's nothing you can do. You could potentially do it server side, but it depends on how the third party system is implementing the redirect.

You got 302 response and redirection request. You can use the fetch API to find out the location attribute in response header

@C3roe I suppose this info should be part of the redirection protocol. Together with redirection code we should get info where redirect to

@C3roe I'm not pretty sure about cors details. However afaik cors blocks cross domain requests. Based on that, whenever the original request is not blocked by client side then any redirects to the same domain should be allowed. Correct me if I'm wrong

I think loremflickr is in maintenance, i had a dummy list of items generated with faker and it worked fine until yesterday, now all images showing a black cat lazying around

fetch("https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris").then(r=>{
    console.log(r.url)
})

this works here and logs https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/defaultImage.small_320_240_g.jpg
but resource can be not allowed to fetch and also fetch loads your image so you load it twice if use both <img src="{url}"> and fetch({url})
